# How to best create a new image out of existing images in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, copy

I have several images which I want to aggregate in a new image 8 image per column, 5 per row side by side with openCV in Python.

Curiously, I did not find an answer which directly addresses this question. From my spare knowledge on openCV, I would now count the width and height of the image to which the existing images should be copied, create a numpy Array with these images and change the values of the corresponding regions of Pinterest to values of each image.

Would this procedure work and more important isn't there an easier solution for this problem which haven't found?

Comment: No, that's the correct approach, and there isn't an easier one. You can get the idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35683236/5008845). Basically create the destination image big enough, and copy each image in the correct position.

Comment: thx, for the answer. Yet, I can not mark the question as answered by just a comment. Maybe you can transform it to regular respons?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When images are read in OpenCV's Python API, you get Numpy arrays. Numpy has `vstack()` and `hstack()` functions, which you can use to stack arrays (images) vertically and horizontally.

Let's open up two images with OpenCV:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

knight = cv2.imread('knight.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

[image]

To use stacking in numpy, there are restriction on the image dimensions depending on the stackng axis (vertical/horizontal), so for this image, I will use `cv2.resize()` to get the right dimensions

```
queen = cv2.imread('queen.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
queen = cv2.resize(queen, (525, 700))
```

[image]

Let's make a first column by stacking 2 Knights

```
col_1 = np.vstack([knight, knight]) # Simply put the images in the list
                                    # I've put 2 knights as example
```

[image]

Now let's make a second column with 2 Queens

```
col_2 = np.vstack([queen, queen])
```

Let's put those two columns together, but this time we'll use `hstack()` for that

```
collage = np.hstack([col_1, col_2]
```

[image]

Et voila, a collage of 2 x 2 which you can adapt to your needs. Note that the images passed in the stacking do need to be identical or anything, you can pass in any list of images, as long as you respect the dimensions.

Comment: how much time consuming is this operation ?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds it useful, here is a quick example of generalizing @bakkal's code to creating a collage out of an **arbitrary** number of images. It creates a collage (for simplicity, a `kxk` square collage, and all images are assumed to be of the same size - o.w, *don't forget to resize your images!*) from a directory of images, by first horizontally stacking images to create `k` rows, and then vertically stacking the rows to create the final canvas.

```
import os


def create_collages(image_dir):
    image_paths = os.listdir
    n = len(image_paths)
    # find nearest square
    collage_size = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(len(good_paths))))

    # horizontally stacking images to create rows
    rows = []
    k = 0 # counter for number of rows
    for i in range(collage_size**2):
        if i % collage_size == 0: # finished with row, start new one
            if k > 0:
                rows.append(cur_row)

            cur_row = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_dir, image_paths[i]))
            k += 1
        else:             # continue stacking images to current row
            cur_img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_dir, image_paths[i]))
            cur_row = np.hstack([cur_row, cur_img])

        # vertically stacking rows to create final collage.
        collage = rows[0]

        for i in range(1, len(rows)):
            collage = np.vstack([collage, rows[i]])

    return collage
```

Comment: what is `good_paths` here?

Answer (score 1):

Resize all the images and are placed in a folder(*input_dir*). Here is simple a solution, *collage_size* parameter says how many images in the collage (r-row, c-col). It will take a random sample of r*c images if there are more images in the folder so that it can give a overall representation. I have been personally using this analyzing variety of objects from training an object detection model.

```
def create_collage(input_dir, collage_size):
    r, c = collage_size
    images_outers= []
    for i in range(r):
        images = []
        for image_name in sample(os.listdir(input_dir), c):
            print(image_name)
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(input_dir, image_name))
            images.append(image)
        image_outer = np.hstack(images)
        images_outers.append(image_outer)
    return(np.vstack(images_outers))
```

Comment: where does sample come from?
in line: for image_name in sample(os....?